# I am trying to fill vector array with getline, what's wrong?

Tags: c++, string, vector, getline

I would like to fill a vector array with some lines but I don't get the same back. What is the problem with my code?

```
using namespace std;

vector<string> calling(int n){
    vector<string> file(n);
    int a=0;

    while(n){
       getline(cin,file[a]);
       cin.ignore();
       a++;
       n--;
    }
    return file;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<string> hrml = calling(n);
    int a=0;
    while(n){
        cout << hrml[a] <<endl;
        a++;
        n--;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

The input:

```
3
aaaa aaa aa
bb b bbbb
c cc ccc
```

The output:

```
aaaa aaa aa
bb b bbbb
```

Comment: Remove `cin.ignore();` after `getline(cin,file[a]);` and add it right after `cin >> n;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a combination of a few factors.

Reading the first number in the input, `3`, doesn't move the "cursor" to the next line; it simply moves it past the number. When you next call `getline`, it returns a `std::string` of size 0, because it grabs the space between the end of the character and the end of the line, which is nothing.

Then, because you're using that number as an explicit number of strings to read, you're reading exactly 3 lines: `""`, `"aaaa aaa aa"`, and `"bb b bbbb"`.

Hence your output missing the line of `'c'`'s.

The simplest solution here is to force an extra call to `getline` before you call `calling`. *(I've removed `using namespace std;` from your code because it's [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice))*

```
int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
```

Then, we can rewrite `calling` to not need an integer parameter:

```
std::vector<std::string> calling(){
    std::vector<std::string> file;
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, line)){
        file.push_back(std::move(line));
    }
    return file;
}
```

*(If you're testing in your console, and you need something to mark the end of the line, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on UNIX.)*

Which changes the calling line to this:

```
std::vector<std::string> hrml = calling();
```

Or this, if you're using C++11 (and don't mind the loss of explicitly visible type declaration):

```
auto hrml = calling();
```

And as long as we're here, we can write a better loop for printing the contents of our vector:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < hrml.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << hrml[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Or, if we're using C++11:

```
for(std::string const& line : hrml) {
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

And, if you're allowed to change the format of your input file, we can ditch the reading of the number in the first place, yielding a much smaller and easier to debug program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

std::vector<std::string> calling(){
    std::vector<std::string> file;
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        file.push_back(std::move(line));
    }
    return file;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> hrml = calling();

    for(std::string const& line : hrml) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about using `std::cin.ignore(1000,'\n');` after reading the number?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews There's nothing stopping you from doing that (... Except for input files whose lines are longer than 1000 characters...) but the code I've written is somewhat more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `std::cin.ignore()` after `getline()` as the latter 'eats' the new line character from the stream. As per the [getline() docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

> Extracts characters from input and appends them to str until one of
>   the following occurs (checked in the order listed):
>   (...)
>
> b) the next available input character is delim, as tested by
>   Traits::eq(c, delim), in which case **the delimiter character is
>   extracted from input, but is not appended to str.**

You do need `std::cin.ignore()` after `std::cin >> n` though as by pressing enter you've put the newline character into the stream and it's going to get eaten by getline, which will return an empty string as a result.

Answer (score 1):

@DimChtz answered your question, but I thought I'd show you how to use for loops since you seem to be fond of clunky while loops:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<string> calling(int n)
{
    vector<string> file(n);

    //for loop
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        getline(cin, file[i]);
    }

    return file;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore();

    vector<string> hrml = calling(n);

    //for each loop (C++11)
    for (auto & str : hrml) {
        cout << str << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
cin >> n;
```

does not remove the new line character from the input buffer. As result the following call of the function `getline` reads an empty string until the new line character is encountered.

This statement in the function

```
cin.ignore();
```

does not make sense. You should place a similar statement after this statement

```
cin >> n;
```

Also if you are dealing with an object of type `int` you should check that it is not less than zero.

Taking this into account the program can look the following way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

vector<string> calling( int n )
{
    vector<string> file;

    if ( n > 0 )
    {
        file.reserve( n );
        string s;

        while ( n-- && getline( cin, s ) ) file.push_back( s );
    }

    return file;
}

int main() 
{
    int n = 0;

    cin >> n;

    cin.ignore( numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

    vector<string> hrml = calling(n);

    for ( const string &s : hrml ) cout << s << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```